# Awk combine for and while loop in algorithm

Tags: linux, awk

I have several hundred text files which I would like to edit using awk. An example of which is

```
5483.39  5134.64  4602.88  3953.89  3271.87  2495.87  1788.98  1285.57  1034.09  1196.25  1851.03  2874.14  3797.68  4361.26  4717.09  4829.74  4760.26  4758.12  4790.80  4763.77  4734.56  3311.89 -811.57 -6152.48
```

I would like to edit using the following algorithm. Starting at the last value (`-6152.48` in this case) I would like to check if the number of counts is less than 85% of that in field 1. If this is true reset this field value to that of $1. I would then repeat for $(NF-1) etc. However, the first time I encounter a field value where this 85% condition is not met (i.e $i > 0.85*$1) I would like to escape the loop and leave all other field as is.

To do this I think I need a foreach loop to scan through each field value and a while loop checking the condition. Here is what I have so far

```
awk 'BEGIN{flag=0} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i] = $i/$1} {for(i=NF;i>=1;i--) print a[i],flag}' file
```

I am unsure how to implement the required logic using awk. i.e for some condition if ($i > 0.85 * $1) flag = 1; then escape the above for loop.

I probably do not need a for and while loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk pseudocode:

```
for(i=NF; i>=1; i--)
{
   if($i>0.85*$1)
      break;
   else
      print $i;
}
```

The `break` statement explicitly serves the purpose of escaping from a loop.